# Solve $x(x+1)=y(y+1)(y^2+2)$ for $x,y$ over the integers

Tags: diophantine-equations

Solve $$x(x+1)=y(y+1)(y^2+2)$$ , for $x,y$ over the integers

Comment: You should try to improve your question by putting on it what you have tried so far. People here will be more interested in help you, if they see that you are interested in learn, instead of just getting the solution of this problem.

Comment: Show some effort towards your own question. Some rather boring solutions are $\;(0,0)\;,\;(0,-1)\;,\;(-1,0)\;,\;(2,1)\;,\ldots$

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution for positive $x$ and $y$.

I will show that
the only solutions 
for positive $x$ and $y$ are
$(x, y) = (2, 1)$ and $(11, 3)$.

$x(x+1) = y(y+1)(y^2+2)
=y(y^3+y^2+2y+2)
=y^4+y^3+2y^2+2y
$

Multiplying by 4,
$(2x+1)^2-1 
=4y^4+4y^3+8y^2+8y 
$
or
$(2x+1)^2
=4y^4+4y^3+8y^2+8y+1 
$

My goal is to show algebraically 
that this polynomial in $y$
is between two consecutive squares
for large enough $y$,
and then examine the remaining cases.

$(2y^2+y)^2
=4y^4+4y^3+y^2
$.

$\begin{align}
(2y^2+y+1)^2 
&=4y^4+4y^3+y^2
+2(2y^2+y)+1 \\
&=4y^4+4y^3+y^2 +4y^2+2y+1 \\
&=4y^4+4y^3+5y^2+2y+1 \\
\end{align}
$.

$\begin{align}
(2y^2+y+2)^2 
&=4y^4+4y^3+y^2 +4(2y^2+y)+4 \\
&=4y^4+4y^3+y^2 +8y^2+4y+4 \\
&=4y^4+4y^3+9y^2+4y+4 \\
\end{align}
$.

For
$(2x+1)^2$
to be between these consecutive squares,
we need
$5y^2+2y+1
<8y^2+8y+1 
<9y^2+4y+4 
$.

The first inequality is true
for $y \ge 1$.

For the second inequality to be true,
we need
$8y^2+8y+1 
<9y^2+4y+4 
$
or
$y^2-4y+3
> 0
$
or
$(y-2)^2-1
> 0$.
This is true for
$y \ge 4$,
so the equation has no solution for $y \ge 4$.

If $y = 3$,
the equation is
$x(x+1) = 3(4)(11)$
and this is true for
$x=11$
(surprise!).

If $y = 2$,
the equation is
$x(x+1) = 2(3)(4)=24$
which has no solution.

If $y = 1$,
the equation is
$x(x+1) = 1(2)(3)$
and this is true for
$x=2$.

Therefore
the only solutions 
for positive $x$ and $y$ are
$(x, y) = (2, 1)$ and $(11, 3)$.

Comment: What happened to $(x,y)=(2,1)$ ?

Comment: I'm fixing that up right now.

Comment: It's not that much harder to extend your argument to the negative numbers. Your inequality will be true for large enough $|y|$

Comment: That is left as an exercise for the reader. Also see my generalization.

Answer (score 2):

I will look  at
$x(x+1) = y(y+1)(y^2+k)$
for integral $k \ge 1$.
This becomes the original question
when $k = 2$.

I will show that
there are no solutions in
positive integral $x$ and $y$
for $y \ge k+2$.

Note  that
$(x, y)
=(k^2-k, k-1)$
and
$(k^2+3k+1, k+1)
$
are solutions to this,
and there is no solution
with $y = k$.
These correspond to
the solutions
$(x, y) = (2, 1)$ and
$(11, 3)$
to the original equation.

This is essentially
my previous solution for
$k=2$
with slightly more complicated algebra.

$x(x+1) = y(y+1)(y^2+k)
=y(y^3+y^2+ky+k)
=y^4+y^3+ky^2+ky
$

Multiplying by 4,
$(2x+1)^2-1 
=4y^4+4y^3+4ky^2+4ky 
$
or
$(2x+1)^2
=4y^4+4y^3+4ky^2+4ky+1 
$

My goal is to show algebraically 
that this polynomial in $y$
is between two consecutive squares
for large enough $y$.

$(2y^2+y)^2
=4y^4+4y^3+y^2
$.

$\begin{align} 
(2y^2+y+k)^2 
&=4y^4+4y^3+y^2 +2k(2y^2+y)+k^2 \\ 
&=4y^4+4y^3+(4k+1)y^2+2ky+k^2 \\ 
\end{align} 
$.

$\begin{align}
(2y^2+y+k-1)^2 
&=4y^4+4y^3+y^2
+2(k-1)(2y^2+y)+(k-1)^2 \\
&=4y^4+4y^3+(4k-3)y^2+(2k-2)y+(k-1)^2 \\
\end{align}
$.

For
$(2x+1)^2$
to be between these consecutive squares,
we need
$(4k-3)y^2+(2k-2)y+(k-1)^2
<4ky^2+4ky+1
<(4k+1)y^2+2ky+k^2
$.

The first inequality is
$0
<3y^2+(2k+2)y-(k-1)^2+1
$
or
$y(3y+2k+2)
>k(k-2)
$
and this is certainly true for
$y \ge k$.

For the second inequality to be true,
we need
$4ky^2+4ky+1 
<(4k+1)y^2+2ky+k^2 
$
or
$y^2-2ky+k^2-1
> 0
$
or
$(y-k)^2-1
> 0$.
This is true for
$y \ge k+2$,
so the equation has no solution for $y \ge k+2$.

If
$y=k-1$,
the right side is
$k(k-1)((k-1)^2+k)
=(k^2-k)(k^2-k+1)
$,
so $x=k^2-k$, $y=k-1$
is a solution.

Similarly, if 
$y=k+1$, 
the right side is 
$(k+1)(k+2)((k+1)^2+k) 
=(k^2+3k+2)(k^2+3k+1) 
$, 
so $x=k^2+3k+1$, $y=k+1$ 
is  a solution.

If $y=k$,
the equation is
$x(x+1)
= k(k+1)(k^2+k)
= (k^2+k)^2
$,
or
$(2x+1)^2-1
= (2k^2+2k)^2 
$, 
which has no solutions for
$k \ge 1$.