# Show that $x(x+1) = y^4+y^3+ay^2+by+c$ has a finite number of positive integral solutions.

Tags: diophantine-equations

More precisely,
If $a$, $b$, and $c$
are integers,
show that
there are only a finite number
of positive integers $x$ and $y$
such that
$x(x+1) = y^4+y^3+ay^2+by+c$.

I have a solution,
which I will show in two days 
if no better one is found.

Comment: I assume you are trying to generalize your http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492581/solve-xx1-yy1y22-for-x-y-over-the-integers

Comment: You may. Or you may not. My lack of control over the external universe has long ceased being a serious issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer. 
Interestingly, it uses no divisibility properties.

We are looking at
$x(x+1) = y^4+y^3+ay^2+by+c$.

I will show that,
if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers,
there are at finite number of solutions in
positive integral $x$ and $y$.
This will be done 
by finding bounds for $y$
in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Multiplying by 4,
$(2x+1)^2-1 
=4y^4+4y^3+4ay^2+4by+4c 
$

or
$(2x+1)^2
=4y^4+4y^3+4ay^2+4by+d 
$,
where
$d = 4c+1$.

My goal is to show algebraically 
that this polynomial in $y$
is between two consecutive 
integer squares
for large enough $y$.

First,

$(2y^2+y)^2
=4y^4+4y^3+y^2
$.

Next,

$\begin{align} 
(2y^2+y+a)^2 
&=4y^4+4y^3+y^2 +2a(2y^2+y)+a^2 \\ 
&=4y^4+4y^3+(4a+1)y^2+2ay+a^2 \\ 
\end{align} 
$.

Finally,

$\begin{align}
(2y^2+y+a-1)^2 
&=4y^4+4y^3+y^2
+2(a-1)(2y^2+y)+(a-1)^2 \\
&=4y^4+4y^3+(4a-3)y^2+(2a-2)y+(a-1)^2 \\
\end{align}
$.

Since
$(2x+1)^2 =4y^4+4y^3+4ay^2+4by+d 
$,
for
$(2x+1)^2$
to be between these consecutive squares,
we need

$(4a-3)y^2+(2a-2)y+(a-1)^2
<4ay^2+4by+d
<(4a+1)y^2+2ay+a^2
$.

I will now show
that both inequalities are true
for large enough $y$.

The first inequality is the same as
$0
<3y^2+(4b-2a+2)y+d-(a-1)^2
$

or
$0 
<9y^2+6(2b-a+1)y+3(d-(a-1)^2) 
$

or
$0 <
(3y-(2b-a+1))^2-(2b-a+1)^2 +3(d-(a-1)^2)
$

or 
$ (3y-(2b-a+1))^2
>(2b-a+1)^2 -3(d-(a-1)^2) 
$

and this is certainly true for
$y$ large enough.

For the second inequality to be true,
we need
$4ay^2+4by+d 
<(4a+1)y^2+2ay+a^2 
$

or
$y^2+(2a-4b)y+a^2-d
> 0
$

or
$(y+(a-2b))^2-(a-2b)^2+a^2-d
> 0
$

or 
$(y+(a-2b))^2
>(a-2b)^2-a^2+d 
=a^2-4ab+4b^2-a^2+d 
=4b^2-4ab+d 
$.

This is true for
$y$ large enough,
so the equation has no solutions for large enough $y$.