# Integer squares of the form $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> I want to solve ${y^2}=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

I can find four solutions.
Is there another solution? I know that there are six solutions.
$$(-1, \pm 1)\;,\;(0, \pm 1).$$ 
My try:
\begin{align}
  & x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0\quad \Rightarrow \underbrace{\left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right)^2}_{t^2}+\underbrace{\left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right)}_{t}-1=0\,\Rightarrow t\notin \mathbb{Z} \\ 
 & x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1={\pm 1}^2\quad\Rightarrow \,x=-1\,\,,\,x=0.\\ 
\end{align}

Thanks.

Comment: See also: [Determining all the positive integers $n$ such that $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ is a perfect square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270599)