# Floyd's Triangle

Tags: contest-math

> The numbers are arranged in a interesting way:
>
> $$ \begin{array}{cccccccc} 1 \\ 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
>  \\ 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\  \vdots \end{array} $$
>
> As you can see, every row has one extra number then the previous row.
>   Using the illustration above to guide you, work out how many numbers
>   lower than 2009 are there in the column containing 2009.

How can we figure out the answer? Is there a repeating pattern of the last number in each row? Can a connection between the ***number of rows***, the ***last number of the rows***, and the ***numbers in a row*** be established?

Comment: Seems like triangular numbers may be useful here!

Comment: The last entry in the $n$-th row is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that each row ends with $1+2+3+4+\dots+n$, a triangle number, since that's how many numbers are in each row above it:

$$\begin{align}1&=\frac{1\times2}2\\3&=\frac{2\times3}2\\6&=\frac{3\times4}2\end{align}$$

etc.

And since $$1953=\frac{62\times63}2<2009<\frac{63\times64}2=2016$$

then it happens to be the case that $2009$ lies on the $63$rd row.  One can deduce this since

$$2009=\frac{n(n+1)}2\implies4018=n(n+1)\approx n^2\implies n\approx\sqrt{4018}\\\implies 62\le n\le 63$$

And then it should be clear that $2009$ is the $56$th number of the $63$rd row, so there are $7$ numbers above it since $63-56$ gives the numbers until you hit the $56$th rows, which beyond that will not have any numbers in the same column.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer! A big, fat thanks. :-)

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine no problem, hope its pretty clear.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine The formula was last # in $n$th row = $n\times(n+1)/2$

Comment: Did you get 62 and 63 by trial and error?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine No.  Notice that$$2009=\frac{n(n+1)}2\implies4018=n(n+1)\approx n^2\implies n\approx\sqrt{4018}$$

Comment: No.  Notice that:$$n(n+1)=n^2+n\approx n^2$$ @SohaFarhinPine

Comment: $56$ is the number of smaller numbers in the same $row$ as $2009$, not the same column. The correct answer is much smaller.

Comment: Nice answer +1 ... @SimpleArt

Comment: @TonyK Oh, ugh, it appears I misread the problem.  I'll see to that.

Comment: @AtulMishra Thank you.  $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @SimpleArt Could you answer my other question: math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070615/…

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Already looking at it ;)  But I think the answer is given in a link in the comments, is it not?

Comment: @SimpleArt not exactly. Someone just gave me his idea on how the problem could be solved. But, I want a more efficient formula to work with.

Answer (score 3):

By the way this triangular shape is constructed, the total number of numbers listed in the first $n$ rows is the sum of the first $n$ integers:
$$1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
according to the formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression (sequence). These are also known as triangular numbers. So you can determine in which row $2009$ is if you solve the inequality $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}<2009$ for the largest positive integer $n$ that satisfies it. Then subtracting $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ from $2009$ will tell you in which column $2009$ is.

Comment: Here $n$ _is_ $2009$.

Comment: No, here $n$ is the last row before the row where $2009$ will appear (so that $2009$ will be in the $(n+1)$-st row).

Comment: Ahh...thanks. I see it now.

Comment: Could you answer my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070615/formula-for-calculating-the-total-number-of-solution-pairs-to-an-equation

Comment: If this answer actually answers your question, could you please accept it?

Comment: I will see. I have to wait for other answers to come too. Of course, if this seems to answer my question in the best way, I will accept it without any hesitation or doubt.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer! A big, fat thanks. :-)

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine: I looked at your other question and left a comment there -- regarding your more general inquiry. As for that specific equation, it had been asked and answered on Math.SE at least twice already, with links available from the page with your question.