# Is there any natural number between $(N^2 + N)$ and $(N^2 + 1)$ that can divide $(N^2 + N)\times(N^2 + 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is fairly simple and explained in title. I'm trying to prove that there are no natural number(s) between $(n^2+n)$ and $(n^2+1)$ that can divide $(n^2+1) \times (n^2 + n)$

[EDIT]

I was trying to solve the problem $n^4 + n^3 + n^2+n+1 = a^2$.

I said that $n^4 + n^3 + n^2+n = (a-1)\times(a+1)$. Refactoring left side, i got:
$(n^2+n)\times(n^2+1) = (a-1)+(a+1)$. It is obvious that $a-1$ and $a+1$ are the closest dividers of $a^2-1$ so i need to prove that, in natural numbers, $n^2+n$ and $n^2+1$ are the closest dividers of $a^2-1$ so i can assume that $(n^2+n) = a+1$ and $(n^2+1) = a-1$ and continue to solve the problem in proper way. Thanks for any help or hint in front.

Comment: Not for small $n$.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Otherwise there exists $a,b$ such that $n^2+1<a\le b<n^2+n$ and $ab=(n^2+1)(n^2+n)$. We must also have $a+b<(n^2+1)+(n^2+n)$. Do you see why?. What can you say about $(a+b)^2-4ab$?

Comment: I have tried, with python, until $10^5$. And found nothing! But i want to prove it formally.

Comment: I can expand that, but please check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619), and try to improve the question with pieces of context, the origin of the question, or partial work (how many values of $n$ have you checked, or some combination thereof.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why $ab=(n^2+n)(n^2+1)$?

Comment: @nonstudent Let $a$ be that factor, and define $b=(n^2+1)(n^2+n)/a$. We can swap the roles of $a$ and $b$ according to which is larger.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270599/11619), and links in there, for more discussion on the problem you started with. The principle *too close to a square to be square* in Jack D'Aurizio's answer is worth remembering (and actually how I was thinking about your problem as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N=(n^2+1)(n^2+n)$. Assume that there exists an integer $A$ such that $A\mid N$ and $(n^2+1)<A<(n^2+n)$. Then the complementary factor $B=N/A$ is also in that interval.

Because $A$ and $B$ are closer to each other than $n^2+1$ and $n^2+n$, and yet $AB=(n^2+1)(n^2+n)$, we must have
$A+B<(n^2+1)+(n^2+n),$ or $A+B\le 2n^2+n$.

But then
$$(A-B)^2=(A+B)^2-4AB\le (2n^2+n)^2-4(n^2+1)(n^2+n)=-4n-3n^2,$$
where the right hand side is negative. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Undoubtedly there is a well known general bound on how "close" can two factorizations of a given number $N$ be. If $AB=N=UV$ then
$$(A+B)^2+(A-B)^2=4N=(U+V)^2+(U-V)^2.$$ So if $|A-B|<|U-V|$ we must also have $|A+B|<|U+V$ et cetera. I could not find a useful dupe, but may be I used wrong buzzwords.

Answer (score 2):

A proof by contradiction. Assume there is a $n^{2}+1+k|(n^{2}+n)(n^{2}+1)$

where $1\leq\,k\,\leq\,n-1$. Then

$n^{2}+k+1|(n^{2}+n)(n^{2}+k-k+1)$ hence $n^{2}+k+1|(n^{2}+n)k$ and then

$n^{2}+k+1|(n^{2}+k+1-k-1+n)k$ hence $n^{2}+k+1|-(k+1-n)k$ and the latter

is positive ($k=n-1$ is not acceptable since it gives $n^{2}+k+1=n^{2}+n$)

which implies that

$n^{2}+1+k\,\leq\,-k^{2}-k+nk$ and hence

$(n-\dfrac{k}{2})^{2}+3\dfrac{k^{2}}{4}+2k+1\,\leq\,0$

which is clearly a contradiction! So there is no such $k$ and the result is proved!

Comment: This is good! ${}$