# Show that if $b^4+b^3+b^2+b+1$ is a perfect square then $b=3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ if $a^2=b^4+b^3+b^2+b+1$ show that $b=3$

These problem appeared in my course of ring theory  i try to use something like the Euler's criterion or maybe Fermat's theorem or maybe by case  but i not sure to these is correct.

Any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining all the positive integers $n$ such that $n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1$ is a perfect square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270599/determining-all-the-positive-integers-n-such-that-n4n3n2n1-is-a-perfe) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E2%3Db%5E4%2Bb%5E3%2Bb%5E2%2Bb%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24b%3D3%24&p=1). Other duplicates also found are [Integer $x$ for which $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is perfect square.](/q/510292), [A quartic diophantine equation](/q/91305), etc.

Comment: This can be directly evaluated since for integer $b$ the inequality $(b^2+b/2)^2<b^4+\dots+1=(b^2+b/2+1/2)^2-(b/2-1/2)^2+1<(b^1+b/2+1)^2$ holds which indicate that $b=-1\text{or}3$

Comment: FYI, the Approach0 search also found various AoPS threads such as [Diophantine equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1739927p11307620), [Number theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2079126p14943001), [Integral solution problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1780928p11733905), etc.